# See log of app in device

Tags: android, android-emulator

When my app is executed in device occurs force close, but in the emulator works fine. How I' can see the log error of device?

Comment: Did you searched you question on google?

Answer (score 0):

To view logcat errors, open the LogCat window by enabling `Window -> Show View -> LogCat`

Comment: But I need this in device, not in pc.

Answer (score 0):

Log cat error will be displayed on the same Log cat. There will be no extra Log cat for any device.

```
Window -> Show View -> Others
```

search for the Log cat

Comment: But I need see the log of device, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a catlog app. Or you can connect your phone through USB (make sure you have driver for your phone insalled) and debug it as you do with emulator.

Comment: But can you explain how? After plugging the phone in usb what I have to do? Just run the app and it will debuged? How to set it to run in debug mode?
Running the emulator is easy to debug, but I never did in the phone.

Comment: @user1352652 It's the same thing. I suppose you are using Eclipse. When your device is USB connected and you start debugging, Android Device Chooser opens up. Then you should see your phone and you can choose it.